# Trying to visualize holdem hand range with percentage distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2

My filling is a gradient and I want to color every cell by different color proportionally to prepared distribution.

My Plot:

[image: My Plot]

Plot that I want to add:

[image: Plot that I want to add]

My code:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill = w[trans[dat$value]]), color = "gray") + 
geom_text(aes(label = pairs$hole_cards[trans[dat$value]])) +
scale_fill_gradient(low = mincolor, high = maxcolor) + 
coord_fixed() + 
theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
axis.title.x=element_blank(),
axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank(),plot.title = element_text(size=20))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
set.seed(1)
df <- cbind(
  within(as.data.frame(replicate(2, sample(1:50,4*4,T)/100)), V3 <- 1-V2-V1), 
  expand.grid(1:4, 1:4)
)
head(df)
#     V1   V2   V3 Var1 Var2
# 1 0.14 0.36 0.50    1    1
# 2 0.19 0.50 0.31    2    1
# 3 0.29 0.20 0.51    3    1
# 4 0.46 0.39 0.15    4    1
# 5 0.11 0.47 0.42    1    2
# 6 0.45 0.11 0.44    2    2
library(ggplot2)
i <- .47
ggplot(df, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_rect(fill="red", aes(xmin=Var1-i, xmax=Var1-i+V1, ymin=Var2-i, ymax=Var2+i)) + 
  geom_rect(fill="darkgreen", aes(xmin=Var1-i+V1, xmax=Var1-i+V1+V2, ymin=Var2-i, ymax=Var2+i)) +
  geom_rect(fill="yellow", aes(xmin=Var1-i+V1+V2, xmax=Var1+i, ymin=Var2-i, ymax=Var2+i)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(Var1, Var2, sep=",")))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]